# Django REST Framework NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

when I try to create a new Post by posting the following JSON:

```
{
    "text": "test",
     "location": 1
}
```

I get the following error:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: grapevineapp_post.location_id
```

models.py:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

views.py:

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

class PostDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

Serializers.py

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    text = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=512)
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    location = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, read_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Post.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.text = validated_data.get('text', instance.text)
        instance.location = validated_data.get('location', instance.location)
        instance.save()
        return instance
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    posts = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Post.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'posts')
```

DB has already been cleared. Locations have been created by using the admin interface. I know that the issue is something trivial, but I just can't get it to work.

Comment: Your `location` is `read_only=True`?

Comment: If I set it to False I get: AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To elaborate on what Willem Van Onsem said, you have your `PostSerializer.location` field set as `read-only`. The json data that you provided for it will be ignored ([documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only)), i.e. it won't be included in your `validated_data`.

Then when you call `Post.objects.create(**validated_data)` in your `create` method it tries to create an instance of `Post` without the location argument and you get your error.

EDIT: After your comment above about queryset.

You need to provide a queryset for it to validate against ([documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)). In your case you want

```
location = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
    many=False,
    queryset=Location.objects.all()
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works as expected. I'm still learning and now I can go on!

Comment: I have a similar issue presently.Can you help me.look into it please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62655168/not-null-constrained-error-on-field-handled-in-views-py

Comment: Wow this answer took me 3 days to find! My QueryDicts kept failing on a foreign key = Null value. This works perfectly. Thanks!