# Unable to POST the data using rest Django - NOT NULL constraint failed: author_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have the following error, and I guess the problem with how can I add the author id to the post automatically.
And also I tried to add null=True

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

The error disappeared, but unfortunately, the author's id is still null.

```
IntegrityError at /auctions/api/addAuction/
NOT NULL constraint failed: auctions_auction.author_id
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/auctions/api/addAuction/
Django Version: 3.1.5
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
NOT NULL constraint failed: auctions_auction.author_id
```

`/auctions/api/serializers.py`

```
class AddAuctionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    print("AddA uctionsSerializer Function call")
    class Meta:
        model = Auction
        # Get the current user from request context
        def validate_author(self, value):
            return self.context['request'].user

        author_id = serializers.Field(source='author.id')
        fields = ["title", "desc", "image","location","min_value","date_added","author_id"]
        read_only_fields = ('author','id','author_id','author.id')
```

`/auctions/api/view.py`

```
class addAuction(APIView):

    #permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    #authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.owner = self.request.user
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        auction = Auction()
        auction.author = request.user

        serializer = AddAuctionsSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(serializer)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`/auctions/api/url.py`

```
path('addAuction/', addAuction.as_view()),
```

`/auctions/model.py`

```
class Auction(models.Model):
    location = LocationField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=False)
   # author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='auction_images/', blank=True, default = 'auction_images/default/default.svg')
    min_value = models.IntegerField()
    #date_added = models.DateTimeField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    winner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET("(deleted)"),
                               blank=True,
                               null=True,
                               related_name="auction_winner",
                               related_query_name="auction_winner")
    final_value = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


    def resolve(self):
        if self.is_active:
            # If expired
            if self.has_expired():
                # Define winner
                highest_bid = Bid.objects.filter(auction=self).order_by('-amount').order_by('date').first()
                if highest_bid:
                    self.winner = highest_bid.bidder
                    self.final_value = highest_bid.amount
                self.is_active = False
                self.save()

    # Helper function that determines if the auction has expired
    def has_expired(self):
        now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
        expiration = self.date_added + timedelta(minutes=AUCTION_DURATION)
        if now > expiration:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    # Returns the ceiling of remaining_time in minutes
    @property
    def remaining_minutes(self):
        if self.is_active:
            now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
            expiration = self.date_added + timedelta(minutes=AUCTION_DURATION)
            minutes_remaining = ceil((expiration - now).total_seconds() / 60)
            return(minutes_remaining)
        else:
            return(0)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django REST Framework NOT NULL constraint failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53687071/django-rest-framework-not-null-constraint-failed)

Comment: did you make sure to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` after you added null=True?

Comment: @RhysJ NO, I tried before I posted the question

Comment: @Yuval, As I mentioned it works! but it arrived null to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using SlugRelatedField instead of Field.

Like so:

```
class AddAuctionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # instead of this:
    # author_id = serializers.Field(source='author.id')
    # do this:
    author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), slug_field='id', write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Auction        
        fields = ["title", "desc", "image","location","min_value","date_added","author"]
        # don't put 'author_id' in read_only, because creating is "writing"
        # also note that 'author.id' is invalid field
        # read_only_fields = ('author','id','author_id','author.id')
        read_only_fields = ('id')

    # Get the current user from request context
    def validate_author(self, value):
        return self.context['request'].user
```

Comment: Could you explain more? Where I suppose to put this line?
Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer, with more detail. hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried your code but unfortunately,still I have an error.
`
FieldError at /auctions/api/addAuction/
Cannot resolve keyword 'author' into field. Choices are: auction, auction_winner, auth_token, bid, date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, user_permissions, username
`

Comment: Sorry i had a small mistake in the code. Change `slug_field='author'` to `slug_field='id'`.

Comment: TypeError at /auctions/api/addAuction/
Got a `TypeError` when calling `Auction.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Auction.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the AddAuctionsSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
Original exception was:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "odels/fields/__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'User'

Comment: Post request
{
    "title" : "test",
    "location" :"[11,11]",
    "min_value" : "100",
    "desc": "hiii",
    "author_id":1


}

Comment: I've updated my answer once again. I rename `authr_id` to `author`. since Auction doesn't have an author_id field. so that is why you are getting that error. hope that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
You can solve it by overwriting the create method of AddAuctionsSerializer and manually defining instance.author, or by passing the parameter author = request.user, to the save method of AddAuctionsSerializer,

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Could you explain more? I'm still new in Django